# JSON source to datatables

Tags: json, datatables

I have this code:

```
testdata = [{
    "hasresults": true,
    "resultscount": 5,
    "dob": null,
    "chart": {
        "rows": [
            {
                "chart": "BAR000",
                "firstname": "RUSSELL",
                "lastname": "BARON"
            },
            {
                "chart": "BAR001",
                "firstname": "BRUSELL",
                "lastname": "BARON"
            },
            {
                "chart": "BAR002",
                "firstname": "GARY",
                "lastname": "BARON"
            }
        ]
    }
}];

$('#test').dataTable({
    "aaData": testdata,
        "aoColumns": [{
        "mDataProp": "chart"
    }, {
        "mDataProp": "firstname"
    }, {
        "mDataProp": "lastname"
    }]
});
```

Can someone help me why is this not working?  It seems that if I removed the following, it will work:

```
"hasresults": true,
"resultscount": 5,
"dob": null,
"chart": {
```

[Not working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/zhea2tbo/1/)

[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4fcukydu/)

Comment: Try switching `"dob": null` to `"dob": empty` See [this for resources on JSON types.](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/json/json_data_types.htm)

Comment: Tried it but doesn't work either.  I'm thinking mDataProp should have chart.rows.chart but it doesn't work either.

Comment: What is the specific exception it's giving you?

Comment: DataTables warning: table id=test - Requested unknown parameter 'lastname' for row 0. For more information about this error, please see http://datatables.net/tn/4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to address `testdata` the correct way. `testdata` is an array holding an object which have another object, `chart`, holding an array, `rows`.

```js
$('#test').dataTable({
    "aaData": testdata[0].chart.rows, //<------
    "aoColumns": [{
        "mDataProp": "chart"
    }, {
        "mDataProp": "firstname"
    }, {
        "mDataProp": "lastname"
    }]
});
```

Your code working here -> **http://jsfiddle.net/j1fvL96e/**

Comment: Thank you.  Was close using it in the mDataProp but instead it should be in the aaData as you indicated.